# Scatter plot of two categorical variables

Tags: r, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I have two categorical variables, which I would like to plot against each other.

This is a dummy example of my data:

```
dummyData <- as.factor(c(rep("fav", 10), rep("int",30)))
dummyMethod1 <- sample(dummyData)
dummyMethod2 <- sample(dummyData)
```

Here is how I tried to plot it:

```
plot(dummyMethod1, dummyMethod2)
```

This gives a bar plot, which is okay, but one cannot see how many data points there were in each category.

or:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(dummyMethod1, dummyMethod2),
       aes(x = dummyMethod1, y = dummyMethod2)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4))
```

This makes a scatter plot, which also doesn't give any information about the number of data point in each category.

Is there any way to make a scatter plot of `dummyMethod1` vs `dummyMethod2` so that I can see each individual data point in each category?

Comment: You can use [`geom_jitter()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html) instead of `geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4))`, does this give expected result?

Comment: Great, that helped! Thanks a lot! 
(And thanks for the editing by the way:))

Comment: consider using `dplyr::count` on the paired columns and using a scaled dot plot instead. a mosaic plot would likely be an alternative as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ggbeeswarm`](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) has some nice options for plotting overlapped points as well

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(data = data.frame(dummyMethod1, dummyMethod2),
       aes(x = dummyMethod1, y = dummyMethod2)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  geom_quasirandom(col = "grey50", varwidth = TRUE, groupOnX = TRUE, alpha = 3/4, size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This one I find even nicer! It even easier to grasp how many points there are in each subcategory.

Answer (score 2):

Using jitter:

```
dummyData <- data.frame(x = as.factor(c(rep("fav", 10))),
                        y = as.factor(c(rep("int",30))))

ggplot(data = dummyData, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]